# SuiteScript 2.0 Apply Time Zone to field

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I need to "GET" a date field from a "Record" and apply a timezone, in 1.0 it was just using the getDateTimeValue and passing the timezone as the second parameter. In 2.0 you only have the generic getValue and when passing the TZ as the second value or passing it in the options package, it seems to just ignore it. Anyone have an idea? I can't find it in the docs.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SuiteScript 2.0 you need to use the [N/format module](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/44521) to apply the timezone to the raw date.

An example of usage is as follows:

```
require(['N/format'], function () {

    var format = require('N/format');
    var now = new Date();
    console.log(now);
    var nyTime = format.format({
        value:now,
        type:format.Type.DATETIME,
        timezone:format.Timezone.AMERICA_NEWYORK
    });
    console.log('NY time is ' + nyTime);
    var gmt = format.format({
        value:now,
        type:format.Type.DATETIME,
        timezone:format.Timezone.GMT
    });

console.log('London time is ' + gmt);
});
```

You can paste the above into the console of a new transaction page and run it to demonstrate how it's used.

Comment: any idea on how getting the time zone from company preference? so the timezone is always depend on the netsuite company preference.

Comment: Use the runtime module to get current user, then `user.getPreference('timezone')`.  Best to post this as a question so I can answer with more detail though (and then others with the same issue could find it too).

Comment: Thanks Krypton. Hi Krypton can you help my question regarding https response in netsuite.